# How to add a string into previous string through loop in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a problem, I want to add a string into previous string and the other string into previous two strings and so on. I don't know how many strings will be. They are may be one, two or hundred. so if you have a solution please you can provide. I want something like this. Basically I have a Multi Selection controls in which user can add many texts so I want to concatenate all the texts that user enter in control.

```
        string one;
        string two;
        string three = one + two;
        string four = one + two + three;
```

Comment: 1) your question is very unclear. 2) can you please specify _one_ programming language?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638044/appending-a-string-in-a-loop-in-effective-way) or perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997455/foreach-string-concat)?

Comment: `They are may be one, two or hundred`, from your post, that would mean you would pre define all your string variables... If you don't know how many there would be, then how would you know how many to define? The question itself doesn't make sense to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you get you will receive your strings, but here is an idea. you can use a couple string arrays to store the previous and next values

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 5;
        string[] words = { "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5" };
        string[] results = new string[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            //handle first case
            if (i == 0)
                results[i] = words[i];
            else
                results[i] = results[i-1] + words[i];
        }
        foreach(string word in results)
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    output:
    word1
    word1word2
    word1word2word3
    word1word2word3word4
    word1word2word3word4word5
```